# identityserver4 RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync unauthorized_client

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I dont know why i get unauthorized_client by using tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync:

[image: RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync unauthorized_client]

Comment: Perhaps password is incorrect? Check the logs they will have more detailed info.

Comment: I have a cutom validation function to validate username and password. I dont know how i can invoke that function ( in my Authorizationserver application) to ensure that validation happens from external call. Do I have to use IExtensionGrantValidator or something???

Comment: It doesn’t look like you have a client with the resource owner grant type in your client store (which is what I imagine is represented in the 2nd screenshot). This could be the reason why it’s not working

Comment: Yes you are right. I also had ti implement IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator. See answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in 3 steps:

Step 1: Implement IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator:
[image: Step 1: Implement IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator:]
Step 2: Granttype (Resource owner password):
[image: Step 2: Granttype (Resource owner password)]
Step 3: Configure the service:

```
   services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```